# How to update the graph model efficiently after certain operation in mxgraph?

Tags: javascript, svg, tree, drag-and-drop, mxgraph

After consecutive drag and drop in mxgraph, the parentInfo is lost for cell.

Children and Parents for cell are not getting updated after consecutive drag and drop.

> Drag and Drop is handled using connect, the logic behind is simple.
> Removing the existing parent connection and establishing new edge
> connection with target node.

```
mxConnectionHandler.prototype.connect = function(
      source,
      target,
      evt,
      dropTarget
    ) {
      var sourceParentCell = getParentCell(source);
      if (sourceParentCell !== target) {
        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try {
          var edges = graph.getEdgesBetween(sourceParentCell, source);
          _.each(edges, edge => {
            graph.getModel().remove(edge);
          });
          graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', target, source);
        } finally {
          graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

**Here goes the click event handler for the cell which provides information about the cell when clicked along with its immediate parent cell info.**

```
graph.addListener(mxEvent.CLICK, function(sender, evt) {
      var cell = evt.getProperty('cell');
      if (cell && cell.id) {
        const nodeData = hierarchialData(graph, cell);
        console.log('cellInfo => ', JSON.stringify(nodeData));
        console.log(
          'parentInfo => ',
          JSON.stringify(getParentCell(cell).value)
        );
      }
    });
```

The above code is working fine for two drags, later the parentInfo is lost and shows the cell itself as its parent.

Deployed in Heroku here: https://express-mxgraph.herokuapp.com/

**Demo:**

[image]

When it reaches to the node: `20-Double click to set name`, you will notice its parentInfo is same: `20-Double click to set name` and not `22-Double click to set name` and hence the edge construction fails miserably.

What's going wrong here, am I updating the vertex and edge properly or not?

Also onload of the url, you may observe the whole graph is dragged towards the mouse move. This also should be avoided.

### Steps to reproduce:

- Move `14-Double click to set name` under `20-Double click to set name`

  Click on `14-Double click to set name`, you will see cellInfo as `14-Double click to set name` and parentInfo as `20-Double click to set name` which is correct
- Now drag `20-Double click to set name` under `22-Double click to set name`

  Click on `20-Double click to set name`, CellInfo and ParentInfo both contains `20-Double click to set name`. ParentInfo actually should contain `22-Double click to set name`.
- So the cell `20-Double click to set name`, it is already in a bad shape and when you now try to connect with `18-Double click to set name`. The graph breaks

Comment: Could write some steps to reproduce your issue please?

Comment: @NickAth - i have demonstrated through gif above. You want me to write those steps?

Comment: In the gif I see straight the error (cellInfo is '12' while it should be '14' am I right?) But I do not see the steps taken before that leaded to this result

Comment: It is correct, cellInfo is the particular cell information, onclick of `14-Double click to set name`, cellInfo will be 14 i.e its own cell id information and there is a parentInfo which gives the value of its cell i.e `12-Double click to set name`

Comment: @NickAth -  have updated the question with steps to reproduce as well

Comment: Could you please provide the getParent function?

Comment: Sure, i have redeployed to heroku with bugfree code caused from the getParent fn and the code is : `function getParentCell(cell) {
  if (cell.vertex) {
    return cell.edges[0].source;
  }
  return '';
}`

Comment: One more important thing which i noticed here is, you just drag and drop under the cell where both are connected to same parent, this is throwing error. 20 -> 22 throws error for me as they are under 16.

Comment: the bug is still reproducible on the heroku app

Comment: Really, Please clear the cache and let me know how i can reproduce. Also thats not the blocker, blocker is parent and children relationship getting broke. By any chance are u suspecting the getParentCell is the culprit?

Comment: Yes I have the cache cleared. What I do is:

1) Add 14 under 20
2) Add 20 under 22

Now the parent info of '20' is '20' while it should be '22'

I suspect that the problem is related to the getParentCell(cell) indeed, maybe it has to do with a wrong reference, could you please try instead of `graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', target, source);` do the following?

`let sourceCopy = source.clone();
graph.removeCells([source]);
graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', target, sourceCopy );`

?

Comment: Boom. It dint work. Uploaded to https://github.com/hansiemithun/node-mxgraph. Plz check

Comment: @NickAth - any luck?

Comment: Which version of mxgraph is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i could not find any references for clone and deep cloning has a bug in jGraph itself and its open issue as well, i managed to solve this having the reference copy of cell and re-constructing the cells under target.

```
mxConnectionHandler.prototype.connect = function(source, target) {
  const nodeData = [{"id":"12","value":"12-Double click to set name","children":[{"id":"14","value":"14-Double click to set name"}]}]
  drawNodes(graph, nodeData, target, source); // recursively
};
```